# Step over JNI_CreateJavaVM crashes program under debug in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, java-native-interface

I am currently working on moving our multi-threaded server app fom VS2013 to VS2017. The port was straightforward enough however i have encountered a weird issue with our use of JNI.

We load the jvm.dll dynamically and then do a GetProcAddress for JNI_CreateJavaVM; this code has worked robustly in VS2013 however in VS2017 i am unable to step over the call to the create JVM function without it reporting a null ptr exception.

Whats wierd is that if i then hit continue to the next break point i find my call to create JVM has succeed and i can then go on to call JNI function to create classes etc.

Anyone got a remedy for this - is it a known issue ?

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017 goto

> Exception Settings - (Ctrl + Alt + E)

and in Win32 exceptions tick `0xc0000005 Access violation`.

JVM generates the mentioned exception when it startups to check OS features. So you can ignore it and move forward.